Tooltip not showing up d3.js version d3 v6
async generateQuadrat(id: any, current_data: any, dimensions?: any) {
    d3.selectAll(`#${id} > svg`).remove();
    console.log(current_data);

    if (!dimensions) {
        dimensions = {
            width: document.getElementById(id).offsetWidth,
            height: document.getElementById(id).offsetHeight,
        };
    }
    const margin = { top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
        width = dimensions.width - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = dimensions.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    const xAxisLabel = current_data.data.data.quadrant.x_axis.label;
    const yAxisLabel = current_data.data.data.quadrant.y_axis.label;
    const xAxisAdditionalLabel = current_data.data.data.quadrant.x_axis.additional_label;
    const yAxisAdditionalLabel = current_data.data.data.quadrant.y_axis.additional_label;

    const bubbleData = Object.values(current_data.data.data.bubble);
    const quadrantData = current_data.data.data.quadrant.data;
    const xRange = current_data.data.data.quadrant.x_axis.range;
    const yRange = current_data.data.data.quadrant.y_axis.range;
    const xMid = (xRange[0] + xRange[1]) / 2;
    const yMid = (yRange[0] + yRange[1]) / 2;

    const svg = d3.select(`#${id}`)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", dimensions.width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", dimensions.height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .style("position", "relative")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

    const x = d3.scalePoint()
        .domain(bubbleData.map((d: any) => d.x))
        .range([0, width])
        .padding(0.5);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", width)
        .attr("y", -5)  // Adjust this value to position near max x
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("font-size", "12px")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .text(xAxisLabel);

    const yMinValue = Math.min(...bubbleData.map((d: any) => d.y));
    const yMaxValue = Math.max(...bubbleData.map((d: any) => d.y));
    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([yMinValue, yMaxValue])
        .range([height, 0]);

    svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("x", -height / 2)
        .attr("y", -margin.left + 15)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("font-size", "12px")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .text(yAxisLabel);

    const xQuadrant = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(xRange)
        .range([0, width]);

    const yQuadrant = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(yRange)
        .range([height, 0]);

    const quadrants = [
        { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: width / 2, y2: height / 2, color: current_data.data.data.quadrant.colors.quadrant3 },
        { x1: width / 2, y1: 0, x2: width, y2: height / 2, color: current_data.data.data.quadrant.colors.quadrant4 },
        { x1: 0, y1: height / 2, x2: width / 2, y2: height, color: current_data.data.data.quadrant.colors.quadrant1 },
        { x1: width / 2, y1: height / 2, x2: width, y2: height, color: current_data.data.data.quadrant.colors.quadrant2 }
    ];

    quadrants.forEach(quadrant => {
        svg.append("rect")
            .attr("x", quadrant.x1)
            .attr("y", quadrant.y1)
            .attr("width", quadrant.x2 - quadrant.x1)
            .attr("height", quadrant.y2 - quadrant.y1)
            .attr("fill", quadrant.color)
            .attr("opacity", 0.3);
    });

    svg.append("line")
        .attr("x1", width / 2)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("x2", width / 2)
        .attr("y2", height)
        .attr("stroke", "#000")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1);

    svg.append("line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", height / 2)
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y2", height / 2)
        .attr("stroke", "#000")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1);

    // Add quadrant descriptions
    quadrantData.forEach((d: any, i: number) => {
        let xPosition, yPosition;

        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                xPosition = width / 4;
                yPosition = height - height / 4;
                break;
            case 1:
                xPosition = (3 * width) / 4;
                yPosition = height - height / 4;
                break;
            case 2:
                xPosition = (3 * width) / 4;
                yPosition = height / 4;
                break;
            case 3:
                xPosition = width / 4;
                yPosition = height / 4;
                break;
        }

        // Add temporary text to measure width
        const tempText = svg.append("text")
            .attr("x", xPosition)
            .attr("y", yPosition)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("font-size", "12px")
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .text(d.description);

        const bbox = tempText.node().getBBox(); // Get the bounding box of the text
        const padding = 10; // Padding around the text

        // Background rectangle
        svg.append("rect")
            .attr("x", xPosition - (bbox.width / 2) - padding)
            .attr("y", yPosition - (bbox.height / 2) - padding)
            .attr("width", bbox.width + 2 * padding)
            .attr("height", bbox.height + 2 * padding)
            .attr("fill", "white")
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
            .attr("rx", 5)
            .attr("ry", 5);

        // Text
        tempText.remove(); // Remove temporary text
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("x", xPosition)
            .attr("y", yPosition)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("font-size", "12px")
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .text(d.description);
    });

    // Additional label for the y-axis, above the center y-axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", margin.left + (height) + 20)  // Center horizontally along the y-axis
        .attr("y", -margin.top / 2)  // Position above the y-axis
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", "12px")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .text(yAxisAdditionalLabel);

    // Additional label for the x-axis, to the right side of the center x-axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", width / 2 + (width / 2 - margin.right) - 35)  // End of the center x-axis considering margins
        .attr("y", height / 2 + margin.bottom - 10)  // Adjust y position as needed
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", "12px")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .text(xAxisAdditionalLabel);

    const minBubbleSize = 4;
    const maxBubbleSize = 40;
    const bubbleSizeScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([d3.min(bubbleData, (d: any) => d.size), d3.max(bubbleData, (d: any) => d.size)])
        .range([minBubbleSize, maxBubbleSize]);

    const tooltip = d3.select('body')
    .append('div')
    .attr('id', 'tooltip')
    .style('position', 'absolute')
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .style('background-color', '#333')
    .style('color', '#fff')
    .style('border', '1px solid #fff')
    .style('border-radius', '5px')
    .style('padding', '5px')
    .style('pointer-events', 'none')
    .style('z-index','100');      

    svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(bubbleData)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", (d: any) => x(d.x))
        .attr("cy", (d: any) => y(d.y))
        .attr("r", (d: any) => bubbleSizeScale(d.size))
        .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
        .style("opacity", 0.8)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .on('mouseover', function(event, d:any) {
            d3.select(`${id}`)
            .transition().duration(200)
            .style('opacity', 1).text(d.x)
        })
        .on('mousemove', function(event:any) {
            d3.select(`${id}`)
            .style('left', event.pageX + 'px')
            .style('top', event.pageY + 'px')
        })
        .on('mouseout', function() {
            d3.select(`${id}`).style('opacity', 0)
        });


    svg.selectAll("text.bubble-label")
        .data(bubbleData)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "bubble-label")
        .attr("x", (d: any) => x(d.x))
        .attr("y", (d: any) => y(d.y))
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", "10px")
        .text((d: any) => d.legend);
}  

While mouse hover the mouseover gets called and executes but the tooltip didnt show up
This is my function for bubble chart along with quadrant's. I had this tooltip issue for last 2 days. Help me to get out of this one. The function of tool tip mouseover and mousemove gets triggered and data flow was correct. But the tool tip dosent come.

The variable ${id} seems to represent the id of the parent container to your svg.  I find it odd that on mouseover, mousemove and mouseout, you attempt to select it at all and you do it as if it was an element.  Did you mean to use d3.select("#tooltip") in those functions?
